# A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "activationConfigParser" is nullable here

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, sonarqube

sonar issue

[image: 1]

```java
private void getGtcj(String gtcjStatusValue, String strArchiveReqd) throws Exception {
    XPathHelper activationConfigParser = null;
    try {
        activationConfigParser = ConfigUtil.getInstance().getConfigParser(new URL((V21Constants.FILE
                + System.getProperty(V21Constants.USER_DIR) + "/vServe21/config/ActivationParameters.xml")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }

    StringBuffer useGTCJSolution = new StringBuffer();
    useGTCJSolution.append(XPathConstants.ACTIVATION_CONFIG_ACTIVATION_PARAM)
            .append("/parameter[@name = '").append(XPathConstants.TAG_NAME_USE_GTCJ_SOLUTION)
            .append("']");

    String useGTCJSolutionStr = activationConfigParser.evaluateXPath(useGTCJSolution.toString());
    log.debug("useGTCJSolutionStr value:" + useGTCJSolutionStr);

    if (useGTCJSolutionStr != null && useGTCJSolutionStr.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(V21Constants.YES)
            && (gtcjStatusValue.equalsIgnoreCase(Statuses.ACTIVATION_SUCCESS)
                    || gtcjStatusValue.equalsIgnoreCase(Statuses.ROLLBACK_SUCCESS)
                    || gtcjStatusValue.equalsIgnoreCase("Rollback Failure"))) {
        log.debug("No need to archive and send response from here.");
    } else {
        log.debug("inside GTCJSolution for GTCJ orders...Archiving and sending response xml");
        if (strArchiveReqd != null && "Yes".equalsIgnoreCase(strArchiveReqd)) {
            archiveXML(responseFileName, V21Constants.VIF_ARCHIVE_RESPONSE_XML_PATH);
        }
        // sending the response XML
        response = new Response();
        response.sendResponseXML(properties, responseXml, bNBSConnectivityFlag, queueName, address);
    }
}
```

I figured out there should be a finally block after catch, but I don't know what to add inside the finally block. Or is there any other solution?

Comment: Could you add what line you are getting the warning/error on?

Comment: getting as A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "activationConfigParser" is nullable here.

Comment: Try to think about what will happen if the code within the `try` block throws an exception: the exception will be caught by the `catch (Exception e) { log.error(e.getMessage()); }` block, but at that point `activationConfigParser` remains `null`, and then `activationConfigParser.evaluateXPath(...)` throws a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Why do you catch that Exception at all there? And what behaviour do you expect from the whole method when this Exception is actually thrown by the code inside the `try` block?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the variable activationCOnfigParser you're in a try/Catch block. You can bypass this error :

```
private void getGtcj(String gtcjStatusValue, String strArchiveReqd) throws Exception {
XPathHelper activationConfigParser = null;
try {
    activationConfigParser = ConfigUtil.getInstance().getConfigParser(new URL((V21Constants.FILE
            + System.getProperty(V21Constants.USER_DIR) + "/vServe21/config/ActivationParameters.xml")));
} catch (Exception e) {
    actionConfigParser = <DEFAULT VALUE>
    log.error(e.getMessage());

}
```

In catch block there is  that you can replace with a value that actionConfigParser has to assuming in case of exception.

Comment: <DEFAULT VALUE> IS THAT YOU CAN REPLACE